VS Code. File contents are not displayed in TERMINAL and OUTPUT
I'm using VSCode on Ubuntu 24.04.01.The screenshot shows a program that reads and displays the contents of a file. The "my_file.txt" contains the word "Hello". When I run the code on the TERMINAL and OUTPUT there is no "Hello" message. How can I print the word "Hello" on the TERMINAL and OUTPUT?
Thanks for the answer
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   
    char buff[100];
  
   FILE *in = fopen("my_file.txt", "r");
    if(in == NULL)
       return 2;

    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    while(ch = fgetc(in) != EOF)
       buff[i++] = ch;
    buff[i] = '\0';
  
    puts(buff);  
        
    fclose(in);
    
    return 0;
}

I tried searching in the settings and in the file task.json...

There are at least three drawbacks in your program.
The first one is that the variable ch should be declared as having type int. Otherwise the result of such a condition like ch == EOF or ch != EOF is implementation defined.
The second drawback is that the condition in this while loop
while(ch = fgetc(in) != EOF)

is equivalent to
while( ch = ( fgetc(in) != EOF ) )

due to the operator precedence and as a result the variable ch will be set either to 1 or 0.
You need to write at least like
while (  ( ch = fgetc( in ) ) != EOF )

And the third drawback is that you should guarantee that the array buff will not be overwritten. So you need to write for example
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char buff[N];
  
    FILE *in = fopen( "my_file.txt", "r" );
    
    if ( in == NULL ) return 2;

    int ch;
    int i = 0;
  
    while ( i < N - 1 && ( ch = fgetc( in ) ) != EOF )
    {
        buff[i++] = ch;
    }

    buff[i] = '\0';
  
    puts( buff );  
        
    fclose( in );
    
    return 0;
}

Also you should be sure that the file indeed exists in the working directory. You could write for example
if ( in == NULL ) 
{
    puts( "File not found." );
    return 2;
}


Thank you! The second drawback was my problem.

@LexusRX No at all. We, beginners, should help each other.:)
